# Convert Volley ArrayList Response data to String

Tags: android, string, arraylist, android-volley

I am using the andriod volley library to get some array of data i want to convert the data into a string but when i tried doing this am only able to get the last data in the array when they are up to ten names only the last name is been converted to string.Here is the code i am using i want to get all the name in as string separated by comma

```
 JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            response -> {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("users");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name = jsonObject.optString("name");

                        ArrayList<String> artistClassArrayList3 = new ArrayList<String>();
                        artistClassArrayList3.add(name);

                        StringBuilder sbString = new StringBuilder("");

                        for(String language : artistClassArrayList3){
                            sbString.append(language).append(", ");
                        }
                        String strList = sbString.toString();
                        if( strList.length() > 0 )
                            strList = strList.substring(0, strList.length() - 1);

                        textView.setText(strList);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error J :: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, error -> Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error R:: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
```

Comment: can you show us your json structure?

Comment: "users": [
    {
      "id": 38,
      "name": "User38"
    },
    {
      "id": 34,
      "name": "User34"
    }
  ],            am able to retrieve it the data successfully in a listView want i want is for to be in string like "user38, user34"

Comment: I think you're replacing the existing text in the text view with each iteration, use textView.append().

Comment: Thanks alot it works just fine